# passing an array to custom directive in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following directive

```
var notInModule = angular.module('ui.notIn', []);

notInModule.directive('notIn', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
        var thisValue;
        var otherValues;

        attrs.$observe('notIn', function(values) {
            otherValues = values;
            validate();
        });

        ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {
            thisValue = viewValue.toLowerCase();
            validate();
            return thisValue;
        });

        var validate = function() {
            ctrl.$setValidity('isWithin', otherValues.some(function(value) {
                return value.toLowerCase() === thisValue.toLowerCase();
            }));
        };
    },
};
```

});

and i am using it like this

```
<input ng-model="sample.name" not-in={{sample}} required/>
```

sample is an array on scope. However , in the directive 's controller , it comes in as a string.

for eg :if `$scope.sample = ["a","b"]` ,

In the directive , values is got as `"["a","b"]"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [angular.fromJson](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.fromJson) for conversion:

```
attrs.$observe('notIn', function(values) {
    otherValues = angular.fromJson(values);
    validate();
});
```

Comment: Works perfectly ! , but why is it getting converted into a string in the first place ? , can you explain me why that happens ?

Comment: Because all DOM attributes should have string as a value :). Think about this - Can you write an html markup, which attributes are of specific type? Actually no !